# Facebook Graph API error code:2500 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have problem here with Facebook Graph API. 
I want to take picture from each post and insert it into gallery, so I make good query and my code looks like this:

```
<script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
       FB.init({
       appId      : '1385526288185078',
       status     : true,
       xfbml      : true,
       version    : 'v2.8'
       });
       FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
       FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
});
       FB.api(
         '/me',
         'GET',
         {"fields":"posts{picture}"},
         function(response) {
             console.log(response);
         }
       ); {scope: 'user_posts'};
   };


(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1239065502849136";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

In console I get error : 
**error:Object 

code:2500 

fbtrace_id:"Em9cGkfMeHX"
message:"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

type:"OAuthException"**

And I am pretty sure that my token is active! Can someone assist what to check or what to do?

Comment: there is no login code, what makes you think that there is an active access token?

Comment: If you logged in to the app before already somewhere, then you at least need to use the `status` parameter in the FB.init call for the SDK to recognize a recurring user.

Comment: @luschn I can share and like, so I thought that it is fine.... But pics does not want to shows up...

Comment: @CBroe When I add status: true, still same error...

Comment: Well did you login in to the app at all before?

Comment: you do not need any login for sharing, or for a like button. please read my answer and make sure you understand what facebook login is. the answer to "did you login?" is only yes or no, there is no "i am pretty sure" - that would be a no ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to authorize the user:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //user just authorized your app

    }
}, {scope: 'user_posts'});
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: Yes this is solution! After while I realize it! Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome. please don´t forget to accept my answer ;)

Comment: btw, you really can´t use FB.login in the init function. you must call in on user interaction. all about that is explained in the second link of my answer.

Comment: My code looks now:  FB.login(function(response) {
                  if (response.authResponse) {
                      console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                      FB.api('/me',  {"fields":"posts{picture}"}, function(response) {
                          console.log(response);
                      });
                  } else {
                      console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                  }
            });
And I get object here so everything is ok.